# SharePoint Online Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-addin, office-365, script

I need automate deployment of apps from repository to SharePoint Online(Office 365). Is there any scripts for PowerShell or another way for automate deployment of Apps?

Comment: The new versions of CSOM allow for this.  Don't know the specifics, but it is possible.

Comment: I think i found some solution for my questions. I hope it will be useful for others http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html

Answer (score 2):

It's achievable through PnP PowerShell CmdLets, you need to install the msi before using it.

```
SPOAppPackage -Path c:\files\demo.app -Force
```

Refer to other switch parameters for more options.

[More details here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/ImportSPOAppPackage.md)

Comment: pnp is quite good, and if it's provider hosted app, you also need to look into Azure PowerShell for the app provision.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting the answer from comment*

Here's [a blog that explains how to use CSOM in powershell scripts with O365](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html).